# Get the data passed from the Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Here is my code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: { s: sToSearch },
    url: 'http://localhost:9809/handlers/search.ashx',
}).done(function (d) {
    sCache[sToSearch.toLowerCase()] = d;
    showResult(d);
});
```

My problem is that when I call this ajax multiple time at a fast rate it will cache a wrong data because `sToSearch.toLowerCase()` will change very fast.

My solution would be getting the data that was passed instead of the actual search string which is this one `sToSearch.toLowerCase()` then cached it.

The question is how can I get the **value** from the **key** `data` (I want to get value `sToSearch` from `s`) of the ajax in the `done` callback function?

something that would look like this

```
.done(function (d) {
        var param = //get the s value of the parameter.
        sCache[param] = d;
        showResult(d);
    });
```

Comment: ***get s value of the parameter*** ... what parameter? Not sure if you question is crystal clear. What is the result of `console.log( d )` inside `done` callback?

Comment: @PeterKA it is a json response from the server. I just want to get the value of the s in the callback function

Comment: The value of s? Wouldn't that be the same as `sToSearch`?  Have you tried to solve your caching problem by supplying `cache: false` in your ajax call?

Comment: @PeterKA Sorry if it was not clear but Guffa did mention using IIFE which works.

Comment: As a sidenote, inside the `done` function `this.url` would contain the URL with the added querystring from the data being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the code in an [IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so that the value of `sToSearch` is kept as a local variable. That way it won't change when the `sToSearch` variable changes:

```
(function(search){}
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: { s: search },
    url: 'http://localhost:9809/handlers/search.ashx',
  }).done(function (d) {
    sCache[search.toLowerCase()] = d;
    showResult(d);
  });
})(sToSearch);
```

Comment: It works thanks.. never new about this.. still learning javascript :))

Answer (score 1):

```
   var search = function(sToSearch){
       $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       data: { s: sToSearch },
       url: 'http://localhost:9809/handlers/search.ashx',
       }).done(function (d) {
         sCache[sToSearch.toLowerCase()] = d;
         showResult(d);
       });

      };

   search("SOMETHING");
   search("SOMETHING Else");
```

if you convert your code snippet to function and if you pass sToSearch as a parameter to it, your sToSearch value will be stay in function context and won't change.